# get next question if exists, if not go back to the start - mysql

Tags: mysql

I have questions about different categories, questions about math, about english...

my table questions:

```
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `question` text NOT NULL,
  KEY `ids` (`id`, `cat_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES categories (`id`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

So, for example, the user is answering question about math (cat_id = 1), he is in question `id 3` (the first one). When he click `NEXT` I pass the question id to mysql to get next one:

```
SELECT id, question FROM questions where cat_id = 1 and id > 3 limit 1
```

With this select I get the next math question (`id 5`). But if it is the last math question I'd like to go back to the first question (for example no id > 6, go to the id = 3):

```
1 - 3(english) - can or may?
2 - 2(history) - Who Discovered America?
3 - 1(math) - 1+1 = ?
4 - 3(english) - can or could?
5- 1(math) - 2+2 = ?
6 - 1(math) - 3+3 = ?
7 - 2(history) - When Was the War of 1812?
```

So how can I go back to the first question of some category if there is not a new one after to select? I'd like to create an infinity loop in questions.

Comment: you can use case

Answer (score 1):

This query should work:

```
select id, question from (
SELECT id, question FROM questions where cat_id = 1 and id > 3 order by id limit 1
UNION
SELECT id, question FROM questions where cat_id = 1  order by id limit 1
) limit 1
```

Select  one record with id greater than your id and the first of all. So if you get no with id greater your id you shoult get the first one

Comment: Thank you, I'll try! this will only select the second query if no record appear in the first one, correct? or this select will always run 2 times? (the select before and after union).

Comment: This selet theresult of the first part of the UNION if there is no it will get the seconad part of UNION @RickJoe

Comment: with some parentheses and as result it worked! thanks! `select id, question from (
(SELECT id, question FROM questions where cat_id = 1 and id > 3 order by id limit 1)
UNION
(SELECT id, question FROM questions where cat_id = 1  order by id limit 1)
) as result limit 1`

Comment: You MUST use `ORDER BY id DESC` over outer query - if not, then a random of 2 records will be returned.

Comment: And, to be a little faster, say `UNION ALL` rather than the default of `DISTINCT`.